# Apollo GraphQL inline fragments error with same fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I have a really weird error when using inline fragments with Apollo.
I have a query that looks like this:

```
{
  allDocuments {
    content {
      ...on StageRecord {
        externalLink
        internalLink {
          slug
          collection {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
      ...on FigureRecord {
        externalLink
        internalLink {
          slug
          collection {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I run this on *GraphiQL* it works like expected. If I run this in my Nuxt app using Apollo I get this error:

```
GraphQL error: Field 'externalLink' doesn't exist on type 'FigureRecord'                                                                                     12:19:13
GraphQL error: Field 'internalLink' doesn't exist on type 'FigureRecord'
```

If I remove this from `StageRecord` or from `FigureRecord` it works:

```
collection {
  slug
}
```

So as long as only one of those fragments queries the collection as well it's no problem. What can I do about that? And why is this no problem in GraphiQL?

The fields `externalLink` and `internalLink` were the ones I added last and I wonder why it's complaining about `externalLink` being not existent when I add `collection` to `internalLink`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your server code being cached somehow?